# Regex to match improper capitalization

Tags: regex, r

I want to write a regex which matches improper capitalization in words or sentences.

For example I want regex should match :
I LoVe YoU SO MUcH!
gOVerNOR

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Something like so should work: `\s+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+`. I am assuming you do not have punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`i` flag](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html), makes the regex case insensitive.

```
string.match("G[a-b].*", "i")
```